# Better way to create new key in map if key doesnt exist in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, data-structures, functional-programming

I have the following `list of maps` in Scala:

```
val list =   List(Map( "age" -> 25, "city" -> "London", "last_name" -> "Smith"), 
         Map("city" -> "Berlin", "last_name" -> "Robinson"))
```

And I wish to iterate through the list of maps and check if the key `"age"` exists. If it doesnt, I want to create the entry and put it in the map. So far I have tried:

```
val tmp = list.map( item => if (!item.contains("age")) item.updated("age",5) else item)
print(tmp)
```

which works fine, I just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way to do it (perhaps with comprehensions or anything else?)! Any advice would be appriciated

Comment: you `list` val type is inferred to `Seq[Map[String, Any]]` because you are mixing int and string value types. So maybe something wrong with the initial list.

Comment: for-comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for `map`, `flatMap` etc. So no effieciency gain there.

Comment: You want to check if at least one map has the key? or all of them have to have it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way.

```
val newList = 
  list.map{m => if (m.keySet("age")) m else m + ("age" -> "5")}
```

Note that if you don't make the value `5` a `String` then the result is a `Map[String,Any]`, which is **not** what you want.

Comment: Why `keySet` instead of `contains`? Sure, it works, but seems less obvious.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same?